# How to format selected text?

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2010

I am trying to format selected text in Outlook 2010.

I recorded a macro that works for Word.

My Outlook code fails on the second line before I get to the working Word code.

I have been using VBA for many years, almost entirely in Excel.

```vb
Option Explicit
Public Sub UseWord_Fmt()
'   Wrapper
    Dim Ins As Outlook.Inspector
    Dim wDoc As Word.Document
    Dim Word As Word.Application
    Dim Selection As Word.Selection

    Set Ins = Application.ActiveInspector
    Set wDoc = Ins.WordEditor
    Set Word = wDoc.Application
    Set Selection = Word.Selection
'
'
    ' My code, generic so that I can later modify
'
'
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
    Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=4, Extend:=wdExtend
    With Selection.ParagraphFormat
        .LeftIndent = InchesToPoints(0)
        .RightIndent = InchesToPoints(0)
        .SpaceBefore = 6
        .SpaceBeforeAuto = False
        .SpaceAfter = 0
        .SpaceAfterAuto = False
        .LineSpacingRule = wdLineSpaceSingle
        .Alignment = wdAlignParagraphLeft
        .WidowControl = True
        .KeepWithNext = False
        .KeepTogether = False
        .PageBreakBefore = False
        .NoLineNumber = False
        .Hyphenation = True
        .FirstLineIndent = InchesToPoints(0)
        .OutlineLevel = wdOutlineLevelBodyText
        .CharacterUnitLeftIndent = 0
        .CharacterUnitRightIndent = 0
        .CharacterUnitFirstLineIndent = 0
        .LineUnitBefore = 0
        .LineUnitAfter = 0
        .MirrorIndents = False
        .TextboxTightWrap = wdTightNone
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the error? Identify the specific line of code.

Comment: Set a reference to the Microsoft Word object model.

Answer (score 0):

*Outlook does not understand `InchesToPoints(0)` When Converting a measurement from inches to points-  simply use **`.LeftIndent = (0)`**, or specify the `Application` Example **`Word.InchesToPoints(0)`***

---

```
Public Sub UseWord_Fmt()
'   Wrapper
    Dim Ins As Outlook.Inspector
    Dim wDoc As Word.Document
    Dim Word As Word.Application
    Dim Selection As Word.Selection

    Set Ins = Application.ActiveInspector
    Set wDoc = Ins.WordEditor
    Set Word = wDoc.Application
    Set Selection = Word.Selection
'
'
    ' My code, generic so that I can later modify
'
'
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
    Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=4, Extend:=wdExtend
    With Selection.ParagraphFormat
        .LeftIndent = (0)
        .RightIndent = (0)
        .SpaceBefore = 6
        .SpaceBeforeAuto = False
        .SpaceAfter = 0
        .SpaceAfterAuto = False
        .LineSpacingRule = wdLineSpaceSingle
        .Alignment = wdAlignParagraphLeft
        .WidowControl = True
        .KeepWithNext = False
        .KeepTogether = False
        .pageBreakBefore = False
        .NoLineNumber = False
        .Hyphenation = True
        .FirstLineIndent = (0)
        .OutlineLevel = wdOutlineLevelBodyText
        .CharacterUnitLeftIndent = 0
        .CharacterUnitRightIndent = 0
        .CharacterUnitFirstLineIndent = 0
        .LineUnitBefore = 0
        .LineUnitAfter = 0
        .MirrorIndents = False
        .TextboxTightWrap = wdTightNone
    End With
End Sub
```